# apt-get update never finishes downloading

Tags: apt, updates

When I run:

```
  apt-get update
```

it will never finish. It'll stop at some random repo (a different one every time I run it) and just keep downloading forever, until the disk is full or until I abort it. Inspecting `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` will show the `.bz2` file of the corresponding repo to be huge.

This started happening after I did a do-release-upgrade from utopic to vivid. I had no such issues when I did the same from trusty to utopic.

I've tried deleting `/var/lib/apt/lists` and rerunning, but the same problem still occurs - it seems that apt-get will just endlessly write garbage bytes to disk.

Edit: this problem seems to be related to the Software Center and its daily update checking. Upon returning to my computer after the automatic update has run during the night, I'll find the disk full and `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial` containing several very large files and an apt-get process along with several orphaned http processes running. If I kill off these, delete `/var/lib/apt/lists` and disable the daily update in Software Center then I can run `apt-get update` successfully.

Comment: For better readability don't post requested output in the comments, [edit] it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening due to repos of both are present in your `sources.list` file
Just open  `vim /etc/apt/sources.list`  and comment or remove the repositories belonging to trusty.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I went through and checked all repos in both `sources.list` and all the files in `sources.list.d/` but all of them were for vivid.

Comment: if you could provide `apt-get update` output.

Comment: Here's the last few lines of output from `apt-get update` run just now (I can find no reasonable tools to make this into a preformatted block, so sorry about the lack of readability):

Hent:78 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en [18,2 kB]                                                         
Hent:79 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en [8 085 B]                                                     
100% [29 Packages 1 615 MB/1 615 MB 100%]

That line at the bottom there will just keep on increasing the MB downloaded indefinitely.